# Set value of Fluent React TagPicker?

Tags: fluentui-react

How does have Fluent React's TagPicker component (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers) render existing tags. I've tried passing in with `input` and `value` props, with no luck. E.g.:

```
<TagPicker value={[{"key": "a", name: "A Tag"}]}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to use `defaultSelectedItems`, e.g.:

```
<TagPicker defaultSelectedItems={[{"key": "a", name: "A Tag"}]}/>
```